# Powershell `install-package` works fine, but `get-package` doesn't show the package installed

Tags: powershell, package-management

In an admin powershell, running:

```
Find-Package Pcsx
```

Shows a package with the name Pcsx. Running:

```
Find-Package pscx | install-package
```

Completes without error. However afterwards:

```
Get-Package Pcsx
```

Returns `Get-Package : No package found for 'Pcsx'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo ? You have spelled `Pscx` wrong twice in your question (`Pcsx`).

Command behaves as expected on my system.

Comment: Well that was embarassing. Thankyou.

Comment: Quite surprising indeed ; had to triple-check before posting : ). We all have our moments.